# Vlookup increases the calculation process time very high

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I have three worksheets within a single workbook. Third sheet has the following Vlookup formula in around 100 rows. This basically looks the data from other two sheets. Everytime, When I Open or close the workbook, it takes around 10 to 15 minutes each time and increasing the computing time. Any workaround suggestions for this ? and If I can use index-match, how do I convert this vlookup to Index-Match ?

Also, since I refer this vlookup to another worksheet (*Worksheet Answers will be cleared and reloads the data to stay updated with the current month**), it gives me when I had to clear the "Answers" worksheet and reload new data. How do I deal with **REF error** in Vlookup ?

Thanks

```
 VLOOKUP(A488&$G$2,Answers!A$2:D$1000000,4,FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you really have a million rows of data?

Comment: Yeah, reducing the rows the the calculation has to perform on will increase performance

Comment: If you are clearing "Answers" by deletion, that would be causing the #Ref error. Instead, you should just be clearing the contents.

Comment: If you can load the information into a table, you can reference that instead of having a hard-coded range in the formula.

Comment: You could also try turning calculation mode to manual and fire off calculations when you need them as a refresh using `F9`, won't do anything to improve performance but it'll reduce the number of times you have to make that 10-15 min wait

Answer (score 1):

> how do I convert this vlookup to Index-Match ?

`=INDEX(Answers!D$2:D$1000000,MATCH(A488&$G$2,Answers!A$2:A$1000000,0))`

Comment: @swiggyswag that'll be because the match could not be found, is the concatenated string `A488 & $G$2` present within `Answers!A$2:A$1000000` exactly? (you would normally wrap the `INDEX()` in an `IFERROR(   ,"")` to produce blanks in the instance that it cannot be found